# CustomErrors DefaultRedirect to Default.aspx Not Working

Tags: asp.net, redirect, error-handling, web-config

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/LogIn.aspx" defaultUrl="~/default.aspx" protection="All">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/default.aspx"></customErrors>
</system.web>
```

This is my error handling in web.config which is not working. If there is any exception thrown  it doesn't redirect to **default.aspx** page.

Is it because I set `defaultUrl`  to `~/default.aspx`? - If not what's wrong with the error handling?

Comment: You should set the Mode "On" for custom errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to have `mode="On"` instead of `mode="Off"`

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/default.aspx"></customErrors>
```

Comment: No worries, some time we miss simple and easy things.

Comment: Durp. I'm baffled as to how that got changed in my project (I certainly didn't change it myself), but yes, that 100% explains why it stopped working at some point.